# Hidden message in pictures 2

Tags: visual, rebus

Find the hidden sentence behind these pictures.

Story starts:

```
"I am in very big trouble.
```

The next sentence:

[image]

*For full size image, right-click the image → open in new tab.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

> **They found some evidence that incriminates me.**

Explanation:

> 1. Pointing to other people -> **They**
>  2. Foul - L + ND -> **Found**
>  3. Seven + Threesome - Ten (Seven+Three) -> **Some**
>  4. (Pokemon) [Eevee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eevee) + Breakdance - Break -> **Evidence**
>  5. T(ea) + Hat -> **That**
>  6. Incr(ease) + Min(e) + Ate + S -> **Incriminates**
>  7. Pointing to oneself -> **Me**

Comment: There's mistake

Comment: In order to make it a little more challenging for you, I'll choose not to say :D

Comment: @mikele Better? ;)

Comment: Post the sentence separately.

Comment: @mikele Done (& improved post a bit)